# Lotuscript IF statements

Tags: lotusscript

I am trying to cycle through multiple fields at once to check if they match a certain value.  For example, a document contains field_1, field_2, field_3 ect. They either have a value of "Yes" or "No".

The statement would be read like this:
`IF field_1 OR field_2 OR field_3 = "Yes"`
I am not trying to test if ALL fields are = to YES.  They should be checked independently.

If it's not too difficult, I would also like to create an IF statement to match 2 group of fields.

Example:
`IF field_1 OR field_2 OR field_3 = "YES"  AND other_1 OR other_2 OR other_3 = "NO"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your fields contain single-value string values, then this will work (using the dot notation syntax):

```
If (doc.field_1(0) = "Yes" Or doc.field_2(0) = "Yes" Or doc.field_3(0) = "Yes") And (doc.other_1(0) = "NO" Or doc.other_1(0) = "NO" Or doc.other_1(0) = "NO") Then
    ' Do stuff
End If
```

This assumes that the doc variable contains a reference to the document in question.

Instead of the dot syntax you can also access the field values using `doc.getItemvalueString("field name")`.

Comment: Is there a way to format it more like this:  {{@if(product_1:product_2:product_3:product_4:product_5:product_6:product_7:product_8:product_9 = "AGITAN 155" ; "Y" ; "N")}}

Comment: You can with Evaluate: `result = Evaluate(|@if(product_1:product_2:product_3:product_4:product_5:product_6:product_7:prod‌​uct_8:product_9 = "AGITAN 155" ; "Y" ; "N")|, doc)` `If result(0) = "Y" Then ... `

Answer (score 0):

You can create a some function and use it in your `If` statement.
For example:

```vb
Function CheckFields(doc As NotesDocument, fields As String, value As String) As Boolean

    Dim fieldsArray As Variant

    fieldsArray = Split(fields$, ":")

    Forall field In fieldsArray

        If doc.GetItemValue(field)(0) = value Then
            CheckFields = True
            Exit Function
        End If

    End Forall

    CheckFields = False

End Function
```

Usage of the function above:

```vb
If CheckFields(doc, "field_1:field_2:field_3", "YES") And CheckFields(doc, "other_1:other_2:other_3", "NO") Then
    'Your code
End If
```

Comment: I like this better than using Evaluate, but since you're talking about fields with the same name except for a number on the end, you might think about having the function support a syntax for fieldnames where you could specify a range or wildcard and have it compare against fields whose names match the pattern.

Comment: @AndreGuirard I'm talking about fields with the same names as example only. In real case there are can be fields with different names.